# tinymce set vaue in document.ready

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

I use tinymce4.2.6 , in master page I have placed this code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">


      tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        directionality: 'rtl',
        plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
        "textcolor"


    ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo  | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent  | fontselect |  fontsizeselect |  forecolor backcolor"


    });

   </script>
```

my problem is I can not load data in my editor. I use setcontent method but it does not work. I have placed this code in my page :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 load_data();

 function loaddata() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../WebService.asmx/loaddata",
            data: "{'id':'" + "1" + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var myData = data.d;


                tinyMCE.get("textareaId").setContent(myData);

            }
        });
    }
});  
 </script>
```

when I alert(MyData); it is correct information but textarea is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wait for the editor to load in order to insert content into it. document.ready won't work in this case. Use:

```
  tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    directionality: 'rtl',
    plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste",
    "textcolor"
],
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.on('init', function(evt) {

      // get your content
      // and insert it into the editor
      ed.setContent(myData);


      });
    },
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo  | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent  | fontselect |  fontsizeselect |  forecolor backcolor"


});
```

Comment: @bahereh: when are you using getContent() ?

Comment: but I have faced with another problem. when I use getcontent() method in button click event, it does not work.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#btn_update", function () {
 var text_one = tinyMCE.get("editor_id").getContent();});});

Comment: is your editor initialized at that point of execution? this looks like another problem which has nothing to do with your former question

Comment: my editor initialized in master page , when I place initialization at its page and remove it from master page .it works fine...thanks